# include_bytes macro won't take argument, even if it is of type &'static str

Tags: rust

I was using glium, and tried to make a struct to make using textures easier. Problem is, the function I am using to initialize the struct takes an `&'static str` as an argument, but the `include_bytes!()` macro won't take it, and the compiler is saying that the argument must be a string literal.
Here's the dysfunctional code:

```
fn load(path : String, format : ImageFormat, display : glium::Display) -> Image{
    let image = image::load(Cursor::new(&include_bytes!(path)[..]),
                        format).unwrap().to_rgba8();
    let image_dimensions = image.dimensions();
    let image = glium::texture::RawImage2d::from_raw_rgba_reversed(&image.into_raw(), image_dimensions);
    let _opengl_texture = glium::texture::CompressedSrgbTexture2d::new(&display, image).unwrap();
    return Image{opengl_texture : _opengl_texture}
}
```

I tried using `String` and converting it in multiple ways, but it still didn't work.

Comment: It’s a macro. Macros work at compile time. Of course it’s not going to work. You need to open the file and read it at runtime. And handle potential failures along the way.

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah, my way of doing things was very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The `include_bytes!` macro is for loading data from a file *at compile-time* and embedding it in the executable. Therefore the path must be known at compile-time via a string literal. Your `path` variable is only known *at run-time*.

Perhaps you wanted [`std::fs::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read.html) instead?

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely try to do that. Thanks for the help !